# Pyinsane example fails with "no module named src.abstract"

Tags: python, importerror, pyinsane

I am using the [pyinsane](https://github.com/jflesch/pyinsane) module, and after running `sudo pip install pyinsane`, I believed that pyinsane was up and running. After testing [this example](https://github.com/jflesch/pyinsane/blob/master/examples/scan.py) with:

```
python /home/administrator/Documents/git-repositories/ramrod/code/main.py /home/administrator/Documents/git-repositories/ramrod/code/test.jpeg
```

I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/git-repositories/ramrod/code/main.py", line 7, in <module>
import src.abstract as pyinsane
ImportError: No module named src.abstract
```

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

from PIL import Image

import src.abstract as pyinsane
```

(There is more code to follow but it is unnecessary to reproduce the issue. All I am looking for is getting rid of this error.)

Comment: does using `import pyinsane.abstract as pyinsane` work? I doubt there is a module named `src`.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yup, perfect! Post it as an answer, quick! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `import pyinsane.abstract as pyinsane`, the `src` module does not exist.